# Not getting value from Shared Preferences instantly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-sharedpreferences

I am storing the data in the Shared Preferences by

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("menu_bar","abcd");
editor.apply();
```

and I am fetching the data from Shared Preferences in fragment by

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String name = preferences.getString("menu_bar","");
if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It is working when the app is removed from the stack.
But on the first time it is not working. Getting NULL in the first time but working fine from the second time. I also tried with `editor.commit()` when saving it.

Comment: What do you mean by "from the stack"? Also, `PreferenceManager` isn't what the official  SharedPreferences documentation uses to open it  so are you sure that works?

Comment: Mostly you creating fragment before saving to SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` and then `commit` to reflect changes instantly

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("menu_bar","abcd");
editor.commit();
```

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the SharedPreferences.
>
> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call apply wins.
>
> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.
>
> As SharedPreferences instances are singletons within a process, it's safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply() if you were already ignoring the return value.
>
> You don't need to worry about Android component lifecycles and their interaction with apply() writing to disk. The framework makes sure in-flight disk writes from apply() complete before switching states.
>
> The SharedPreferences.Editor interface isn't expected to be implemented directly. However, if you previously did implement it and are now getting errors about missing apply(), you can simply call commit() from apply().

Comment: The last sentence of the question mentions using commit method

Comment: @user12345: Still I am getting the same issue. For the first time I am getting NULL. Second time it is working fine.

Comment: First time value will be null because nothing is saved in shared pref at that time but can set default value while getting it from sharedpref.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same instance of SharedPreferences. Easiest would be an explicitly named one:

```
class MyActivity {
  private static final String PREFS_NAME = "myActivityPrefs";
  private static SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = null;
  public static SharedPreferences prefs(Context context) {
    if (sharedPrefs == null) {
      sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    }
    return sharedPrefs;
  }
}
```

You then use it in the activity like this:

```
prefs(this).edit().putString("menu_bar","abcd").apply()
```

And in the fragment:

```
String name = MyActivity.prefs(getActivity()).getString("menu_bar","");
```

This is a recommended mode of operation that would give you good performance without waiting for I/O on your main thread - `apply()` does that for you but requires using the same instance to be consistent.

To use separate instances (sometimes you're forced to - for example through separate processes) always use `commit()`, which can freeze your main thread at times, and *still* doesn't guarantee consistency due to how filesystems work, I've seen instances where `commit()`ed data wasn't immediately available to a separate process, often on specific devices that had a FS configuration quirk.